# Aesthetic error in R ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, aesthetics

I'm trying to fill watersheds by amount of water used by fracking. I have the dataset(well_watershed_ok) and the variable(H2O_BBL_T). There is one value for each watershed. This was the code I was using.

```
ggplot() + 
geom_polygon(data = well_watershed_ok, aes(x = long, y = lat), 
             fill = well_watershed_ok$H2O_BBL_T) + 
labs(x = "", y = "", title = "Number of Barrells of Water used per Day") + 
scale_color_gradientn("Water BBL/Day", colors = c( "#660000", "#f9f3c2")) + 
theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.ticks.y = element_blank(), 
      axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks.x = element_blank(), 
      axis.text.x = element_blank(), 
      plot.title = element_text(lineheight = .8, face="bold",  vjust = 1, size = 12)) + 
coord_equal(ratio=1)

Regions defined for each Polygons
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (222074): fill
```

Because I got this error I check my lengths and they are equal but then I checked to see if the computer recognized that they were equal and it was false. What do I do?

```
identical(well_watershed_ok,well_watershed_ok$H2O_BBL_T)
[1] FALSE

length(well_watershed_ok)
[1] 79

length(well_watershed_ok$H2O_BBL_T)
[1] 79
```

Here is what my data looks like

```
data.frame':    79 obs. of  37 variables:
$ FID_1     : Factor w/ 79 levels "0","1","10","11",..: 1 2 13 24 35 46 57 68 
78 79 ...
$ HUC_8     : Factor w/ 68 levels "11040001","11040002",..: 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 
7 ...
$ ACRES     : num  26176 420687 188128 1281 657 ...
$ HU_8_NAME : Factor w/ 68 levels "11040001 - CIMARRON HEADWATERS",..: 1 2 3 3 
3 3 4 5 6 7 ...
$ STATES    : Factor w/ 8 levels "AR,OK","AR,OK,TX",..: 5 7 3 3 3 3 3 7 7 7 ...
$ SQ_MILES  : num  40.9 657.32 293.95 2 1.03 ...
$ Count_    : Factor w/ 40 levels "0","1","10","12",..: 1 14 17 2 1 34 1 20 26 
16 ...
$ Sum_Lat_Y : num  0 73.8 775.6 37 0 ...
$ Sum_Long_X: num  0 -204 -2111 -101 0 ...
$ Sum_DF_Ele: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Sum_GF_Ele: num  0 7691 54745 3223 0 ...
$ Sum_Total_: num  0 9389 144678 6720 0 ...
$ Sum_OilBBL: num  0 0 0 0 0 0 0 181 166 698 ...
$ Sum_Oil_Gr: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Sum_GasMCF: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Sum_GasOil: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Sum_WaterB: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ H2O_BBL_T : num  0 642 0 0 0 ...
$ FID_12    : Factor w/ 79 levels "0","1","10","11",..: 1 2 13 24 35 46 57 68 
78 79 ...
$ FID_12_13 : Factor w/ 79 levels "0","1","10","11",..: 1 2 13 24 35 46 57 68 
78 79 ...
$ HUC_89    : Factor w/ 68 levels "11040001","11040002",..: 1 2 3 3 3 3 4 5 6 
7 ...
$ ACRES_1   : num  26176 420687 188128 1281 657 ...
$ HU_8_NAM_1: Factor w/ 68 levels "11040001 - CIMARRON HEADWATERS",..: 1 2 3 3 
3 3 4 5 6 7 ...
$ STATES_1  : Factor w/ 8 levels "AR,OK","AR,OK,TX",..: 5 7 3 3 3 3 3 7 7 7 
...
$ SQ_MILES_1: num  40.9 657.32 293.95 2 1.03 ...
$ Count1    : Factor w/ 39 levels "0","1","107",..: 1 24 2 1 1 14 1 31 5 22 
...
$ Sum_DF_E_1: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Sum_GF_E_1: num  0 12299 2499 0 0 ...
$ Sum_Total1: num  0 20844 6950 0 0 ...
$ Sum_OilB_1: num  0 20 0 0 0 ...
$ Sum_Oil__1: num  0 0 0 0 0 ...
$ Sum_GasM_1: num  0 20 0 0 0 ...
$ Sum_GasO_1: num  0 1000 0 0 0 ...
$ Sum_Wate_1: num  0 642 0 0 0 ...
```

Comment: Does it work if you put the `fill` specification inside the `aes` call? Try `ggplot(well_watershed_ok, aes(x=long, y=lat, fill=H2O_BBL_T) +geom_polygon()`. Your may also need to specify the `group` aesthetic.

Comment: No, I get the same error. What do you mean by specify the group aesthetic? Sorry, I am new to R

Comment: It should be `geom_polygon(data = well_watershed_ok, aes(x = long, y = lat,  fill = well_watershed_ok$H2O_BBL_T))` since you are using fill as part of mapping.

Comment: > ggplot()+geom_polygon(data=well_watershed_ok, aes(x=long, y=lat,fill=well_watershed_ok$H2O_BBL_T))+labs(x="", y="", title="Number of Barrells of Water used per Day")+scale_color_gradientn("Water BBL/Day", colors=c( "#660000", "#f9f3c2"))+
Regions defined for each Polygons
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (222074): x, y, fill

Comment: I still get the same error

Comment: Please put an example of your data, e.g. `head (well_watershed_ok)` or `str(well_watershed_ok)`. Hard to tell what the problem is without understanding the data format.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `scale_color_gradientn(...)` with `scale_fill_gradientn(...)`, since your aesthetic is fill (the painted inside of the polygon) not colour (the line bordering the polygon).

Also, don't use `dataframe$variable` in `ggplot` calls as a general rule. Like @mikeck and @marcelo mentioned above, you want to specify all your aesthetics that vary along with the data to be inside an `aes(...)` statement, where you can just write the unquoted column name:

```
ggplot(well_watershed_ok, aes(x=long, y=lat, fill=H2O_BBL_T) + 
  geom_polygon() + 
  scale_fill_gradientn(name = "Water BBL/Day", colors = c("#660000", "#f9f3c2"))
```

Finally, you need to make sure that `well_watershed_ok$H2O_BBL_T` is a numeric vector. Try `str(well_watershed_ok)`. If it says that that column is a factor, then R has interpreted your data as being categories, not a continuous variable. A common cause is when you have a list of numbers with `.` to represent missing values; R will read that as a list of text instead.

In the future, make sure to include a reproducible snippet of your data for diagnosing your problem.

Comment: Thank you for your help, When I don't use dataframe$variable, then it does not recognize the variable                                                                              '> ggplot(well_watershed_ok, aes(x=long, y=lat,fill=H2O_BBL_T))+geom_polygon()+labs(x="", y="", title="Number of Barrells of Water used per Day")+scale_fill_gradientn("Water BBL/Day", colors=c( "#660000", "#f9f3c2"))'
Regions defined for each Polygons
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'H2O_BBL_T' not found

Comment: Thank you for your help, When I don't use dataframe$variable, then it does not recognize the variable                                                                              `> ggplot(well_watershed_ok, aes(x=long, y=lat,fill=H2O_BBL_T))+geom_polygon()+labs(x="", y="", title="Number of Barrells of Water used per Day")+scale_fill_gradientn("Water BBL/Day", colors=c( "#660000", "#f9f3c2"))`
Regions defined for each Polygons
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'H2O_BBL_T' not found, also I did the str test and the variables are numbers

Comment: It sounds like the error is somewhere upstream in your code then. You should provide a minimal reproducible example, see: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and 
 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example